# ARM Cortex M4f microcontroller on a breadboard

Tags: arm, cortex-m4, usbasp

I recently bought an ARM based microcontroller from Texas Instruments ([MSP432P401R](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP432P401RIPZR)). However I found out too late that it is not a in a Dual In-line Package and so I cannot use it on a breadboard. What do I do in order to use it on a breadboard?

Additionally, can I use USBASP to program this microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

You do not. You buy the development board, in your case the [MSP-EXP432P401R](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp432p401r), and you use wires to the breadboard.

Or you buy a development board you can breadboard, [mbed](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/) has some.

Putting this category of chips on a breadboard gives you a deluxe package of problems, if you are going that way, you'd better start funding this website.

---

You program that chip with an SWD or JTAG programmer. Like Segger, ULink or with the upper part of the [MSP-EXP432P401R](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp432p401r) development board. It has an [XDS110](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/XDS110) debugger on board.

Comment: Almost all development boards for this type of MCU come with a USB to SWD debug interface on the board (typically implemented with another small MCU). These can be re-used as generic debug interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, you typically use a breakout board.

A 100 pin breakout board is not a very nice thing though, especially if you want to go to DIP.

So something like [this](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/images/PRODUCTS/PA0109_0.JPG?osCsid=l4pnriq28rkgvs06khc910c652):
[image: QFP 100 breakout]

You have to be careful to select the correct footprint, as there are quite a few variations around with different pin pitch.

Note that these adapters might cause problems because of their non matched length of the lines and maybe long lines on the supply pins.

---

I don't know the details of the USBASP, but the short description reads:

> USBasp is a USB in-circuit programmer for Atmel AVR controllers.

As you have a TI MSP432, a Cortex M4F at heart, I'd say: No you cannot use it.

Comment: This will probably have big problems with interference and glitching, due to the long traces between the chip and decoupling capacitors

Comment: @BeB00 yeah, I wrote that a year ago in my answer already. But you can always opt to place some decoupling caps on the pins directly with some fly wire action.